# How can I disable font scalling for the entire application at once

Tags: react-native

I want to disable font scalling for the entire application at once, I disabled it setting useFontScalling to false in  but I don't want to do it in this way, please let me know how can I disable it at once, no need to write useFontScalling for each and every file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For removing font-scaling in whole App paste this code in `App.tsx` | `App.js`

If you are using TS:-

```
interface TextWithDefaultProps extends Text {
    defaultProps?: { allowFontScaling?: boolean };
}

((Text as unknown) as TextWithDefaultProps).defaultProps =
    ((Text as unknown) as TextWithDefaultProps).defaultProps || {};
((Text as unknown) as TextWithDefaultProps).defaultProps!.allowFontScaling = false;
```

If you are using JS:-

```
Text.defaultProps = Text.defaultProps || {};
Text.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = false;
```

Comment: Thanks mate, this finally is a solution for TS, as it is not obvious. Should be just some prop in the config file...